# Get the row and column in a canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, game-development

I am making a minimap for players to see each other in the world. I want to add a sector indicator which tells the individual player which sector they are in. The world is a 5000x5000 matrix.
[image: Minimap]

Comment: Take the `(x,y)` coordinate, divide by the size of each sector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the scale of the world and divide by the rows and columns to get the scale. Then divide the players x, y by the scale to get the sectors. I made `COLUMNS` and `ROWS` arrays in case you want to change to naming system. This method returns a string.

```js
function getSector(x, y) {
  // The dimensions of the map
  const WIDTH = 5000, HEIGHT = 5000;
  // The sectors row and column labels
  const COLUMNS = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
  const ROWS    = ['A','B','C','D','E'];
  // Scale map to number of sectors
  const colScale = Math.floor(WIDTH / COLUMNS.length);
  const rowScale = Math.floor(HEIGHT / ROWS.length);
  // Convert xy coordinates to sectors
  const col = Math.floor(x / colScale);
  const row = Math.floor(y / rowScale);
  // Returns string of current sector
  return `${ROWS[row]}${COLUMNS[col]}`;
}


console.log(getSector(0, 0))
console.log(getSector(4999, 4999))
```

Comment: the rows and columns are reversed, B1 cordinates record A2 instead of B1. Sectors go horizontally by letter.

Comment: @TimaDonbragoni wasn't sure which way you ordered it, I just swapped `ROWS` and `COLUMNS` so it should be good now

Comment: yeah i debugged it aswell, thank you for this! You are a true champion! You dont need to use rowscale btw